Mark 6:54 - Who knew/recognized Jesus: the disciples or the crowds?

51 And he went up unto them into the ship; and the wind ceased: and
they were sore amazed in themselves beyond measure, and wondered. 52
For they considered not the miracle of the loaves: for their heart was
hardened. 53 And when they had passed over, they came into the land of
Gennesaret, and drew to the shore. 54 And when they were come out of
the ship, straightway they knew him.  (KJV)

My question is "who knew him, the disciples or the people generally?" Most modern translations render vs. 54 to indicate that the people of the area recognized him because he was now a famous miracle-worker. But Mark depicts the disciples as failing to truly understanding Jesus because "their hearts were hardened." Matthew, on the other hand, mentions no hardness of hearts and affirms that they paid him homage:
Matthew. 14:

32 And when they were come into the ship, the wind ceased. 33 Then
they that were in the ship came and worshipped him, saying, Of a truth
thou art the Son of God.

The reason for all this context is that the KJV version of Mark's story could imply that the disciples did not recognize Jesus as the Son of God when he entered the boat but they did know him (in some sense) soon afterward. Other translations clarify (rightly or wrongly) that it was the crowds who recognized Jesus.
The question again: who knew/recognized Jesus in Mk. 6:54?

Short Answer: The pattern and following verses at the very least seem to support that it was the people who recognize Jesus.
Modern translations do seem to clearly indicate it was the people rather than the disciples. The following verses lend support to this:


Mark 6:54-56 ESV - And when they got out of the boat, the people    immediately recognized him and ran about the whole region and began to bring the sick people on their beds to wherever they heard he was. And wherever he came, in villages, cities, or countryside, they laid the sick in the marketplaces and implored him that they might touch even the fringe of his garment. And as many as touched it were made well.


We also perhaps see this hinted at in a previous verse because the people were there before they arrived:


Mark 6:33 ESV - Now many saw them going and recognized them, and they    ran there on foot from all the towns and got there ahead of
them.


At this point Jesus had taught, he had healed people, and expelled demons while traveling around Galilee.

The dawn had now broken, and the people on shore at once recognised
the Great Healer, and craved His help in behalf of their sick and
afflicted. (Cambridge Bible for Schools and Colleges)

The commentaries seem to agree that it was the people:


And when they were come out of the ship, straightway they knew him—"immediately they recognized Him"; that is, the people did. (Jamieson-Fausset-Brown Bible Commentary)



upvoted. I wish I could "accept" more than one answer.

The answer to this question is contained earlier in V33 which forms part of the introduction to the miracle of the feeding of the 5000

Mark 6:31-33 - And He said to them, “Come with Me privately to a
solitary place, and let us rest for a while.” For many people were
coming and going, and they did not even have time to eat. So they went
away in a boat by themselves to a solitary place. But many people
saw them leaving and recognized them. They ran together on foot from
all the towns and arrived before them.

Following this miracle and after refusing to be crowned king, Jesus dismissed the crowd and crossed to the other side of the lake.  Mark records this:

Mark 6:53-55 - When they had crossed over, they landed at Gennesaret
and moored the boat. As soon as they got out of the boat, the people
recognized Jesus and ran through that whole region, carrying the sick on mats to wherever they heard He was.

Thus, following this great miracle of feeding the multitude and wanting to crown Jesus, Jesus was very well-known - people rush from the surrounding towns to have the miracle worker heal their sick.

This has to be the right answer. My question arose from a recent comparison of Mark and Matthew, which highlighted Mark's criticism of the disciples' failure to understand. It seems that in Mark, they did not "get" the fact that Jesus was the Son of God until Peter's confession.

@DanFefferman - the impression I get is that the disciples were so overwhelmed by the master they were serving that at times they appear to be almost sleepwalking through the experiences.  For example, Jesus told them several times that He had to go to Jerusalem to be tortured and killed and then rise on the 3rd day.  But they were still surprised when it all happened.

at present I am studying Mark and trying to think what it would be like in the early church if I had only Mark's gospel (the earliest one IMO) and a few letters of Paul to go by. I think I would have a much lower estimate of Peter and the apostles compared with having the entire NT. I would also know far fewer of Jesus' teachings.

@DanFefferman - while that is obviously true, recall that all of Jesus' teach was oral and much more information was circulating that we probably now have access to.  I sometimes wonder of the Holy Spirit inspired the NT writers to record what they did before the oral memories faded or were corrupted.

In Mark 6:54, "they" refers to the crowd that recognized Jesus when He got out of the boat. The disciples had already recognized Jesus when He got on the boat, ahead of the crowd.
Furthermore, let's address a related question: Why does Matthew 14:33 claim the disciples worshipped Jesus as the Son of God, while Mark 6:52 says their hearts were hardened?
The gospels vividly reveal the development of faith and its struggles due to human weakness or affliction by Satan. A striking example is seen in Matthew 16:13-23 and Mark 8:27-33, where Peter declares that Jesus is the Messiah, only to be rebuked by Jesus shortly after for being influenced by Satan.
It may seem that the disciples' hearts were hardened because they did not understand the miracle of feeding the 5000, focusing on the physical act rather than its spiritual significance. However, walking on water was undoubtedly perceived physically as a miracle. Even then, they declared Jesus as "the Son of God" rather than "Messiah" as later Peter recognized.
This highlights the necessity of the Holy Spirit's coming.

I'm particularly interested in Mark's attitude toward Peter and the other 12 as compared to Matthew's attitude. Matthew portrays them as recognizing him as the Son of God when he joined them in the boat, but Mark does not say this but reports that "their hearts were hardened." And when Peter finally declares Jesus to be the Messiah in Matthew, Jesus gives him the keys to the kingdom. In Mark Peter does not receive the keys. One can easily conclude that Matthew's view of Peter and the 12 is more positive than Mark's.

In my opinion, Mark's comment is similar to John's frequent assertions that the disciples did not understand Jesus (John 8:27, 8:43, 10:6, 12:16,16:18,20:9). If they did understand, the disciples might either have the Holy Spirit with them or not need the Holy Spirit at all. Matthew's gospel is most effective for discipleship study. It is well organized to connect the dots rather than merely presenting facts, as is often the case in Mark. Therefore, I believe it is unnecessary to speculate about their personal emotions towards individuals.
